# Having a error with implementing add task into my project

Tags: java, android

I have ad task manager working in another projec, but when I converted the code it gave me an error when I tried to run it. The error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInf {com.screenssample/com.sudarmuthu.android.taskmanager.ViewTasksActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
```

and I do not know how to find errors by debugging it, but shouldn't be any errors if it works in another project correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
```

It seems you are trying to cast one class type to another type which are no way related. Some code may help in getting more accurate answer.

Comment: so what do you think is the best way to change the type?

Comment: Okay so is the error coming from the manifest you think? Because I just copied and pasted the java files and res files into my project and recieved that error